# Identify routing rule applying to a given destination

Tags: linux, routes

I have a complex routing table. I want to ping a certain host, and would like to know which routing rule is responsible for performing the routing for that specific destination.

I do not want to perform this computation by myself, but delegate this to the component responsible of performing the routing: the linux kernel.

Is there any system tool that will tell me which rule in my routing table will be used when targeting a specific host / network?